Solidity Contract require not taken into account when deployed with Node
// Lottery.sol

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .001 ether, 'Value must be greater than .001 Ether');
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }
}

// deploy.js

const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const { abi, evm } = require('./compile');

provider = new HDWalletProvider( myphrase, myinfura );

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    try {
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

        // works, but should revert the contract
        const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
            .deploy({ data: '0x0' + evm.bytecode.object })
            .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0], value: '1000000000000000' }); // .001 ETH
        
        console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    } finally {
        provider.engine.stop();
    }
};

deploy();

When deploying the contract in Remix "require" works fine, but with Node deployment the requirement is not taken into account when the value is equal or less than 0.001 ETH. The contract will be not reverted then.
Any ideas?

When I use Remix I call the enter function explicitly. I think I have to do this in my "deploy.js" as well?

The enter function is not called during deployment, only constructor. So the require doesn't apply in this case
